# Is it appropriate to visit your workplace before you start work?

Tags: work-environment, offices

I'm starting work at a small company in a month and will be moving to the city the office is in. I will be visiting that city before hand to meet up with a friend. Would it be considered proper to drop into the workplace on that day just to say hi?

The workplace seems to have a very friendly atmosphere and they have taken me out to dinner before. i just do not want to bother them if they seem busy, but on the other hand its a small office with like 4-5 people and I would like to develop a friendly relationship with them.

Comment: No, not a good idea.  They don't like overzealous people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perfectly acceptable, in fact to be encouraged.   I would however pre-arrange it with them in case of deadlines etc.

It's also worth having a quick chat with your manager about what you'll be doing when you start, maybe you'll need to know about certain aspects that are new to you and can read up in the run up, also shows you are keen on the job.

You could also do something nice like bring donuts, will help the cordial mood.

Comment: Cheers for the answer and advice. It's not a problem anymore as just this morning they invited me to a dinner party, so I'll just go to that instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 outcomes if you visit (arranged):

1. They love it, you're the first person to ever do this and you become their new favourite employee
2. They don't mind the visit, but it has no effect one way or the other
3. They find it a bit weird/strange/unusual

If you don't visit there are two outcomes:

4. They wanted you to visit, now they are worried you don't like them
5. They didn't expect it so everything carries on as normal

As 1 is the only one that benefits you and is very unlikely, the best outcome you can hope for from visiting them is the same as the best outcome from not going (because 4 is equally unlikely) and you'll still get chance to make good first impression on your actual first day.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is appropriate as long as they give prior consent to it. DON'T drop in unannounced - that could be very disruptive to them.
2. Maybe you should reconsider your idea because your visit will inevitably disrupt their workflow, but you can (hopefully) minimize the impact by vising after hours.
3. It's a small office so you should be comfortable with the environment within a few hours, regardless of whether you intend to visit.
4. If you made the arrangements and they expect you to show up and you find out that you cannot show up, you'll have to call in to cancel :) That issue does not arise if you chose not to visit :)